# sorting on multiple aggregations

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation, elasticsearch-aggregation

Say I have documents like so, in a people index:

```
{
    zip: string, 
    birthDate: Date,
    graduationDate: Date,
    marriedDate: Date,
    deathDate: Date,
    ...
}
```

I want to be able to do a single query to elastic search where I retrieve several different counts of records, all with a birthDate within a specific range, then a secondary term query like graduationDate:* or marriedDate:*, then grouped by zip. The kicker is that I want to be able to sort by these counts.

So far I have this:

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
                {
                    "query_string": {
                        "query": "birthDate:[1979-03-01 TO 1979-03-31]",
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        “total”: {
            "aggs": {
                "group_by_zip": {
                    "composite": {
                        "sources": [
                            {
                                "zip": {
                                    "terms": {
                                        "field": "zip"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "graduated": {
            "filter": {
                "query_string": {
                    "query": "graduationDate:*",
                }
            },
            "aggs": {
                "group_by_zip": {
                    "composite": {
                        "sources": [
                            {
                                "zip": {
                                    "terms": {
                                        "field": "zip"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "married": {
            "filter": {
                "query_string": {
                    "query": "marriedDate:*",
                }
            },
            "aggs": {
                "group_by_zip": {
                    "composite": {
                        "sources": [
                            {
                                "zip": {
                                    "terms": {
                                        "field": "zip"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "died": {
            "filter": {
                "query_string": {
                    "query": "deathDate:*",
                }
            },
            "aggs": {
                "group_by_zip": {
                    "composite": {
                        "sources": [
                            {
                                "zip": {
                                    "terms": {
                                        "field": "zip"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I can't figure out how to SORT this by, say, the _docCount of married:desc and get the same collection of zips for each of the aggs. There are 41692 zip codes, so this needs to page obviously.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
                {
                    "query_string": {
                        "query": "birthDate:[1979-03-28 TO 1979-03-31]",
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "group_by_zip": {
            "composite": {
                "sources": [
                    {
                        "zip": {
                            "terms": {
                                "field": "zip"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "aggs": {
                "total": {
                    "filter": {
                        "query_string": {
                            "query": "*"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "graduated": {
                    "filter": {
                        "query_string": {
                            "query": "graduationDate:*"                        }
                    }
                },
                "married": {
                    "filter": {
                        "query_string": {
                            "query": "marriedDate:*"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "died": {
                    "filter": {
                        "query_string": {
                            "query": "deadDate:*"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "sort_it": {
                    "bucket_sort": {
                        "sort": [
                          {"graduated>_count": {"order": "desc"}}
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```